# Brownian motion reflection principle under the general stopping time

Tags: brownian-motion, markov-process, stopping-times

For a general stopping time $\tau$, we define $\hat{B}(t)=B(t)1_{\{t\leq \tau\}}+(2B(\tau)-B(t))1_{\{t>\tau\}}$.

I know the strong Markov property $B'(t)=(t+\tau)-B(\tau)$ is also a Brownian motion and it's independent of $F_{\tau}$. And I also know to get $\hat{B}$, it involves gluing of $B$ and $B'$. The main goal is to prove $\hat{B}$ is also a Brownian motion.I tried proving independence and stationary by splitting the stopping time, and finite dimensional distribution method, but both didn't work.

Comment: Oh, yes. I accidentally typed $\hat{H}$, that should be $\hat{B}$.

Comment: If you are allowed to use Itô integral and related results, then $$\hat{B}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}(1-2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{s>\tau\}})\,\mathrm{d}B_s\qquad\text{and}\qquad t=\int_{0}^{t}(1-2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{s>\tau\}})^2\,\mathrm{d}s,$$ hence $\hat{B}$ [has the same law as the standard Brownian motion](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/).

Comment: I finally found that the same finite dimensional distribution is enough to prove it's a Brownian motion. It uses the characteristic function method.

Answer (score 1):

We follow Theorem 5.2.13 in [Probability theory II](https://petergracar.github.io/files/WT2.pdf), 6.13 Theorem in R.Schilling and [Proving the reflection principle of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720236/proving-the-reflection-principle-of-brownian-motion).

On the event that $\tau$ is finite, by the strong Markov property the path

$$(g_{1}(t)=B_{t+\tau}-B_{\tau})_{t\geq 0}, (g_{2}(t)=B_{\tau}-B_{t+\tau})_{t\geq 0}$$

is a Brownian motion independent of $(B_{t})_{t\leq \tau}$. We define the concatenation mapping

\begin{equation}
\Phi : \mathbf{C}_{(0)}\times[0,\infty)\times\mathbf{C}_{(0)} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}_{(0)},
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{C}_{(0)} := \{f \in \mathbf{C}[0,\infty) : f(0) = 0\}$, thus

\begin{equation}\Phi(f,t,g) := \begin{cases}
f(s), & 0 \leq s < t \\
f(t) + g(s - t), & t \leq s < \infty
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

This map $\Phi$ is continuous if we equip $\mathbf{C}_{(0)}\times[0,\infty)\times\mathbf{C}_{(0)}$ with the topology of locally uniform convergence (in $\mathbf{C}_{(0)}$) and pointwise convergence (in $[0,\infty)$). Therefore, it is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbf{C}_{(0)})\otimes\mathcal{B}[0,\infty)\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbf{C}_{(0)})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbf{C}_{(0)})$-measurable.

This continuity is easy to see by taking sequences $(f_{n},t_{k},g_{m})\rightrightarrows (f,t,g)$ and studying $\Phi(f_{n},t_{k},g_{m}), \Phi(f,t,g)$ by splitting the supremum over $t_{k}$.

From here the result follows easily by using the $\Phi$-map to concatenate $g_{1},g_{2}$ separately to $(B(t))_{t\leq \tau}$.